# 3 data related RecyclerViews, each in one page of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have `ViewPager` with 3 tabs. In each of them is one `RecyclerView`. Each of the `RecyclerView` has it's own `Adapter`. I have one singleton class called `GlobalData` and in that class I have 3 `ArrayLists` containing data for each `Adapter`. To be more specific, first tab displays **months**, second tab displays **weeks** and third one **days**. Only **days** can be changed, added or removed. **Weeks** and **months** should be adjusted accordingly.

One **day** represents day spent in work. I have already implemented logic for added, removing and changing **days** as well as logic for adjusting **weeks** and **months**. But I need a really efficient way for notifying `Adapters` that data was changed, removed or modified.

I can achieve this by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` of each adapter when scrolling to the tab of `ViewPager`.

```
tabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        switch (position) {
            case WorkingFragmentAdapter.DAYS_PAGE:
                daysAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;

            case WorkingFragmentAdapter.WEEKS_PAGE:
                weeksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;

            case WorkingFragmentAdapter.MONTHS_PAGE:
                monthsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;
        }
    }
```

But such a code is really time consuming when there is large set of data displayed in the `RecyclerView` and the performance of the app is low.

I was thinking about a way where I would remember position of every modified, added and removed position of **days**, **weeks** and **months** and when scrolling to the page is performed, notify `Adapter`.

Second way that occurred to me was to store reference of each `Adapter` in `GlobalData` and notify each adapter from `GlobalData`.

Could you please tell me or hint me what would be the best solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through something like this where a user action could affect as many as six different fragments along with their respective adapters.  While the user is interacting with the UI, they are swiping the view pager and fragments are being created/destroyed in random fashion.

After starting with a design that created a lot of bugs, I rewrote the code to have the correct design.  Let me share what I learned:

- Start by having a class that is specifically for the model of your UI. In your case, an instance of your class will have a list of months, a list of weeks, and a list of days.  It will also have things like the currently selected month/week/day and any other data that captures the current state of the UI.
- I wouldn't recommend a global data singleton.  Instead, have the Activity hold a reference to the model object.  When a fragment is in `onCreate()`, it's easy enough to call `getActivity()` to find the clearinghouse for the model object.  There is a very good reason for this: your model will need to be persisted and recreated on configuration changes.
- So to that end, your model class should implement `Parcelable` and have all the necessary logic to save and restore its state.  Then override the activity's `onSaveInstanceState()` method to save the model with `Bundle.putParcelable()`.  And when the activity is in `onCreate()`, check the saved instance state and restore the model if necessary.
- For the adapters, your model class should provide methods to get the data, such as `getMonthList()`, `getWeekList()`, `getSelectedWeek()`, `getSelectedDay()`, etc. etc.  The fragments will call these methods in `onCreateView()` to set up their adapters and bring up the UI in the correct state. **Important:** Any methods that return collections like a list of months/weeks/etc. should return an immutable *array*, not just a reference to the list in the model.  You want the clients to have a completely separate reference to the list, or there will be side effects as changes to the model affect the adapters *immediately* and cause `RecyclerView` to crash since `notifyDataSetChanged()` hasn't been called.  That single piece of advice will probably save you about a week's worth of frustration.
- Your model class will be both a receiver and transmitter of UI events.  On the receiving side:  you will define some methods like `selectWeek(week)`, `selectDay(day)`, etc. that inform your model of something the user just did.  The method will make the data change then inform all the listeners of the event, discussed next.
- On the transmitting side: Your model class should define at least one interface – I'll call it `CalendarUIListener` – that will define callback methods for all the ways that the model can change.  Some examples: `onWeekSelected(week)`, `onDaySelected(day)`, `onMonthListChanged(List<month>)` etc. etc.  Your model will also need to maintain a list of listeners through two methods `addListener()` and `removeListener()`.
- Your view pager fragments can implement this interface to receive the event notifications.  These view pager fragments should call `model.addListener(this)` in `onCreate()` and `model.removeListener(this)` in `onDestroy()`.  Alternatively, the fragments can create anonymous listener objects and register/unregister those instead of implementing the interface directly.
- Now your listener can receive events and respond accordingly.  Suppose your user selects a week which changes the day list (let's assume you have a `Day` class and a custom adapter).  Your code might look like this:

  ```
      @Override
      public void onDayListChanged(Day[] days) {

          if (mAdapter != null) {
              mAdapter.setDays(days);  // this method would call notifyDataSetChanged()
          }
      }
  ```

This is an example of a home-grown event bus.  There are also event bus libraries you can use to make all the wiring a little easier (i.e. calling `addListener()` & `removeListener()` in the right places).  My particular application had some additional challenges like retrieving data from the server whenever a UI event occurred, then broadcasting that data event when the request completed.  Using this architecture made it a lot easier to figure out which class was responsible for what action.

One last thing: I did run into a chicken/egg problem with configuration changes where the fragments were apparently recreated in activity's `super.onCreate()` which didn't give me a chance to restore the model from the saved instance state in the activity.  I coded an abstract base class that implemented the listener for my fragments so my code looked like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment implements Model.Listener {

    private Model mModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (mModel == null) {
            mModel = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).getModel();
        }

        if (mModel == null && savedInstanceState != null) {
            mModel = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("model");
        }
        // debug - throw error if model is null at this point
        model.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        model.removeListener(this);
        model = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable("model", mModel);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    ...
}
```